# Customize validation on node_form

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I have a created a content type in Durapl7, and now I want to customize the validation for the add form on the website.

Please see attached image for what I got so far,  [image]

But my main problem is Validation, in durapl the validation (see the validation message in attached image) is showing all at once at the bottom, but I want it differently, see the bellow image

[image]

Now, here I want each field to be validated separate on each field change, and it will show valid or invalid message with each field.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you chekked this https://www.drupal.org/project/ife module? The solution seems to be in functions ife_element_errors_set and theme_ife_form_element

Comment: thanks @user20301, is it not possible without a moudle? , because the validation required there is very much custom, and I will be doing my own JS validation.

Comment: Nope, you will need a module anyway. If the validation you require is purely done in javascript I think you should just build custom module to inject your script in to the form. Check hook_form_alter, drupal_add_js and Drupal behaviors to get started on the functionality.